# What is the best way to hide GCP token in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have this file `token.json` which is a service token I downloaded when using `GCP` service account. So I am using this token in my repository.

But I need not anyone to publicly view this token.

This is how it looks like: (some values i have removed)

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "possible-origin-236919",
  "private_key_id": "e6a2d1400d077701190559b5c94804357ce4f0ce",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "banuka-terraform@possible-<>",
  "client_id": "<>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<>"
}
```

I can't even use `gitlab` variables, since it can be accessed only from `.gitlab-ci.yaml`. So What is the best way for this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a vault service like https://www.vaultproject.io/ is the better approach, but, if you do not have this option you can create a job to retrieve this token from an external localtion, like another repo, s3 or file server

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Never store a password or key in a git and use a centralized secrets management

GCP offers a product named [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) that allows you to store sensitive data in a secure environment and in a secure way. On [Accessing a secret version](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#access) section explains how to adapt your code to use this service.

Google created a brief a blog entry named [Improving your security posture with centralized secrets management](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/improving-your-security-posture-with-centralized-secrets-management) where it clearly explains how to use this tool to store secrets and how to integrate third party services such as GitHub Actions and Terraform.

Comment: This is not about `gcp` really. This is about `gitlab`. I need to mask this file in `gitlab`

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. Removing GCP tag.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not about gcp really. This is about gitlab. I need to mask this file in gitlab

True, but I just want to mention that, since [GitLab 16.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/#gcp-secret-manager-support) (Jan. 2024), you now have (for non-free GitLab):

> ### GCP Secret Manager support
>
> Secrets stored in GCP Secret Manager can now be easily retrieved and used in CI/CD jobs.
>
> Our new integration simplifies the process of interacting with GCP Secret Manager through GitLab CI/CD, helping you streamline your build and deploy processes!
>
> This is just one of the [many ways GitLab and Google Cloud are better together](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/08/29/gitlab-google-partnership-s3c/)!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_8/gcp_secrets_mgr.png]

See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/gcp_secret_manager.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/11739).

---

In your case, if you want to leverage GCP Secret Manager, you can store your `token.json` as a secret in GCP and then access it in your GitLab CI/CD pipeline. That method is more secure but also more complex.

You would:

- store your `token.json` content in GCP Secret Manager.
- follow the GitLab documentation to set up the integration with GCP Secret Manager in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
- fetch the secret during the CI/CD process and use it as needed.